# JavaScript isn't working for calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a calculator using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript. I've tested my HTML and CSS with several validators, but on adding the JavaScript functions, my buttons on the calculator aren't working. Nothing is displayed on the screen and none of the functions are being called. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Adding link to the .css page now -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "calculator.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
    <title>Calculator Front-End</title>

</head>

<body>
        <form>

            <input type = "text" id = "screenid" class = "screen" name = "calcscreen" value = "0">

            <p>
                &nbsp;
            </p>


            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">7</button></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">8</button></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">9</button></td>
                    <td><button id = "add" class = "symbolbutton" onclick="addDisp(this)">&plus;</button></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">4</button></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">5</button></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">6</button></td>  
                    <td><button id = "sub" class = "symbolbutton" onclick="addDisp(this)">&minus;</button></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">1</button></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">2</button></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">3</button></td>
                    <td><button id = "prod" class = "symbolbutton" onclick="addDisp(this)">&times;</button></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button class = "digitbutton" id = "digit" onclick="addDisp(this)">0</button></td>
                    <td><button id = "result" class = "symbolbutton" onclick="doCalc(this)">&equals;</button></td>
                    <td><button id = "div" class = "symbolbutton" onclick="addDisp(this)">&divide;</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form> 
</body>
</html>

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> ****`And here's my calculator.js file:`****

```
//Defining the variables and constants I need for my functions

var previousvalue = 0; //Last button pressed
var newvalue = 0; //Current button being pressed
var previousop = 'plus';
var previnputcn = 'symbolbutton' //Classname of the previous button

//Writing the function to display elements on screen

function addDisp(button) 

    {

    //Assume if the button pressed is a digit:
        if (button.classname == "digitbutton") //Suppose button pressed = 5
            {
                if (previnputcn == "symbolbutton") //Suppose previous button pressed was a symbol
                {
                    newvalue = document.getElementById("digit").value; //New value becomes 5
                }

                else 
                {
                    newvalue = newvalue + document.getElementById("digit").value; 
                    //Previous button pressed was a digit, so current display is appended
                }
            }

        document.getElementById("screenid").value = document.getElementById("screenid").value + newvalue; //Print Everything on Screen

        if (button.classname == "symbolbutton") //Suppose button pressed was a symbol
            {
                var calcResult = doCalc(previousvalue, newvalue, previousop);

                if (calcResult <= 1000000 || calcResult == "ERROR") 
                {
                    newvalue = calcResult;
                }

            document.getElementById("screenid").value = document.getElementById("screenid").value +newvalue;

                if (newvalue == "ERROR")
                    {
                        previousvalue = 0; //Re-initalize last value to 0 in case of an error

                    }

                else 
                    {
                        previousvalue = newvalue; //Re-update current value as last value to continue calculation
                    }

                previousop = button.id; //Last operation gets id of the current operation button

            }
        previnputcn = button.className; //Last button classname stored for reference for future calculations

    }


/*Writing the doCalc() function which handles all the calculations*/

function doCalc(newvalue, previousvalue, previousop)
    {
        var output = newvalue;

        if (previousop == "plus")
            {
                output = parseInt(previousValue) + parseInt(newvalue);
            }
        else if (previousop == "minus") 
            {
                output = parseInt(previousValue) - parseInt(newvalue);
            }
        else if (previousop == "times")
            {
                output = parseInt(previousValue) * parseInt(newvalue);
            }
        else if (previousop == "divide")
            {
                if (newvalue != 0)
                    {
                        output = parseInt(previousValue) / parseInt(newvalue);
                        output = parseInt(output);
                    }   
                else 
                    {
                        output = "ERROR";
                    }
            }
        calcResult = output;
    }
```

Comment: any errors in console? __CTRL+SHIFT+C__

Comment: or command+alt+i

Comment: No errors in the console :(

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have several elements with the same id.

Comment: Assuming these files are in the same directory, your JS is loaded and running the functions. However, you have a typo if the element's class name. Try using `className` with a capital N instead. I will continue debugging.

Comment: Changed classname to className as per Phillip's suggestion, and also removed the same <id> from all by digit buttons, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

1. Specify the type of each button as type="button". The default type for button is "submit" which will cause the form to be submitted on clicking. Your page is getting refreshed everytime the buttons are clicked.
2. Most of your buttons have the same id. Id is supposed to be unique.

You are anyways passing the button element as argument to the addDisp function on click. Use it to fetch the value.

Comment: So I made both the changes, but it still won't help.